# Pig schema and type anomaly

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

It's very simple demo that can reproduce the problem at 0.11.

===testSchemaDATA===

```
1_a
2_b
3_c
```

the first script:

```
a = load 'testSchemaDATA' as (str:chararray);
a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2)) as num;
a2 = foreach a1 generate (int)num as num;
dump a2;
```

it is right script and dump he answer:

1
2
3

The second and wrong script is (The only difference of two scripts is schema declaration of a1 statement.):

```
a = load 'testSchemaDATA' as (str:chararray);
a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2)) as (num,char);
a2 = foreach a1 generate (int)num as num;
dump a2;
```

it report
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1052: 
 Cannot cast bytearray to int

I don't know how to explain this. is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
a = load 'testSchemaDATA' as (str:chararray);
a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2)) as (num:int,char:chararray);
a2 = foreach a1 generate num as num;
dump a2;
```

will give you output:

```
(1)
(2)
(3)
```

And

```
a = load 'testSchemaDATA' as (str:chararray);
a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2)) as (num:int,char:chararray);
a2 = foreach a1 generate char as char;
dump a2;
```

will give your output:

```
(a)
(b)
(c)
```

The difference is, in this case you are explicitly casting the result of STRSPLIT as int and chararray. If not given, it will default to bytearray.

If you do `a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2)) as num;`
Then `describe a1` gives

```
a1: {num: bytearray}
```

if you do 
`a1 = foreach a generate flatten(STRSPLIT(str,'_',2)) as (num,char);` then `describe a1` gives:

```
a1: {num: NULL,char: NULL}
```

It looks like type is coming as null in this case. I am not sure why this is so. If anyone can tell, would be great.